# Laradock - The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laradock

I'm trying to set up my project on VPS using Laradock and am getting an error

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services: 'couchdb'
Unsupported config option for networks: 'frontend'
Unsupported config option for volumes: 'phpmyadmin'
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d nginx mysql`

It seems that this problem appears when `.env` file does not exist or is invalid.

The problem is that my .env file exists and has the proper format/data. Same with docker-compose.yml

Locally I followed the same steps(MacOs) and everything worked without any problems.
What am I doing wrong here?

Folder structure

```
| home
|    | project
     |       | laradock
             |        | .env
             |        | .docker-compose.yml
             |        | ... other laradock stuff
```

OS - Ubuntu 20.04

Docker - 20.10.21, build 20.10.21-0ubuntu1~20.04.2

docker-compose - version 1.25.0, build unknown

docker-compose.yml I use - https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

.env.example - https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/.env.example

Comment: Unfortunately I'd have to see that `docker-compose.yml` to reproduce your problem. If you're really not using `couchdb` then just remove it from the docker-compose.yml, but then you're still stuck with the frontend and phpmyadmin errors

Comment: @UnderDog Sorry, my bad. I tried removing certain services but it just causes errors in other services. docker-compose.yml and .env.example are quite big, so I added links to them, hope it's ok

Comment: It's best if you include your files directly in the question, because when links expire or change the question becomes much less useful to future readers. You don't need to include the entire file if it's large; you only need a [mcve] that is sufficient to reproduce the problem you're asking about.

Comment: This is Laradock, services stripped and all services moved to the 'docker' folder: https://github.com/UnderDogg/InvoicePlane-v2-Docker it's from some time ago, so put php to version 8.1 etc. If you fork Laradock to your own github and place your changed files in there, it's easier to help you. Default Laradock should work out of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally solved it by simply adding

`version: "3"`

At the beginning of the `docker-compose.yml`

Though I have no idea why Laradock did not include it by default or why it worked locally.